What about first and second comment?
At the beginning of the movie, Princess Irulan narrates:

Imperial Diary. Year 10, 191, third comment. The battle for Arrakis
took everyone by surprise.

What about first and second comment?

They were, respectively, "First!" and "Second too!!", and were removed by moderators. It's nice she finally learned to post significant comments.

We don't know. These diaries and various other fictional works don't exist in their entirety. The purpose of them is to contrast the young and highly ethical Paul Atreides with the future god Muad'dib. They also introduce us to Princess Irulan, and by extension, her father the Emperor, as a person of importance in Paul's future.
In the source novel, Irulan read excerpts from a range of books that she has evidently authored on a fairly singular topic; Muad'dib and his conquest of Arrakis.
“A Child’s History of Muad’Dib”

You have read that Muad’Dib had no playmates his own age on Caladan.
The dangers were too great. But Muad’Dib did have wonderful
companion-teachers. There was Gurney Halleck, the troubadour-warrior.
You will sing some of Gurney’s songs, as you read along in this book.
There was Thufir Hawat, the old Mentat Master of Assassins, who struck
fear even into the heart of the Padishah Emperor. There were Duncan
Idaho, the Swordmaster of the Ginaz; Dr. Wellington Yueh, a name black
in treachery but bright in knowledge; the Lady Jessica, who guided her
son in the Bene Gesserit Way, and — of course — the Duke Leto, whose
qualities as a father have long been overlooked. -from “A Child’s
History of Muad’Dib” by the Princess Irulan

and “Dictionary of Muad’Dib”

YUEH (yu’e), Wellington (weling-tun), Stdrd 10,082-10,191; medical doctor of the Suk School (grd Stdrd 10,112); md: Wanna Marcus, B.G. (Stdrd 10,092-10,186?); chiefly noted as betrayer of Duke Leto Atreides. (Cf: Bibliography, Appendix VII [Imperial Conditioning] and Betrayal, The.) -from “Dictionary of Muad’Dib” by the Princess Irulan

and “Muad’Dib, Family Commentaries”

How do we approach the study of Muad’Dib’s father? A man of surpassing warmth and surprising coldness was the Duke Leto Atreides. Yet, many facts open the way to this Duke: his abiding love for his Bene Gesserit lady; the dreams he held for his son; the devotion with which men served him. You see him there — a man snared by Destiny, a lonely figure with his light dimmed behind the glory of his son. Still, one must ask: What is the son but an extension of the father? -from “Muad’Dib, Family Commentaries” by the Princess Irulan

and “The Humanity of Muad’Dib”

Many have marked the speed with which Muad’Dib learned the necessities of Arrakis. The Bene Gesserit, of course, know the basis of this speed. For the others, we can say that Muad’Dib learned rapidly because his first training was in how to learn. And the first lesson of all was the basic trust that he could learn. It is shocking to find how many people do not believe they can learn, and how many more believe learning to be difficult. Muad’Dib knew that every experience carries its lesson. -from “The Humanity of Muad’Dib” by the Princess Irulan

Etc, etc. Each starting and ending at the relevant part.

She also authored

“Manual of Muad’Dib”,
“Collected Sayings of Muad’Dib”
“In My Father’s House”
“Songs of Muad’Dib”
“Conversations with Muad’Dib”
“Arrakis Awakening”
“Muad’Dib: Conversations”
“Private Reflections on Muad’Dib”
“The Wisdom of Muad’Dib”
“Muad’Dib, the Man”
“Count Fenring: A Profile”
“The Collected Sayings of Muad’Dib”
“Muad’Dib: The Religious Issues”
“Muad’Dib: The Ninety-Nine Wonders of the Universe”
“Collected Legends of Arrakis”

Note that none of the above exist beyond an excerpt introducing us to the topic of the succeeding chapter.

Irulan, the royalty with royalties.

@lfurini - Known for her spicey fiction.
